# How to connect AWS Aurora serverless database to Next.js app

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-aurora-serverless

I am trying to connect my Next app to an Aurora serverless MySQL database instance by I can't get it to work.

I am trying to use the [RDS data api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html), but my Next api functions keep timing out.

Has anyone got any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: If my answer below doesn’t work you’ll need to add more details about your infrastructure

Comment: Is your app running in VPC? Does it have a network route to the internet or to the RDS data API via [VPC endpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/02/amazon-rds-data-api-now-supports-aws-privatelink/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to everyone for your suggestion. I managed to get this to work.

The server doesn't need to be in the same VPC as the db.

I used this package to connect - [data-api-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-api-client)

Here's how I connected:

```
const dataApi = require('data-api-client');

const RDS = dataApi({
  secretArn: process.env.SECRET_ARN,
  resourceArn: process.env.RDS_ARN,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  options: {
    region: process.env.REGION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
});
```

After turning on the data api on the database, I then had to create a secret in the secrets manager that is connected to the database. Then I created a new I AM role that gave full access to the database and secrets manager.

After that everything worked as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately Serverless V2 no longer supports Data API

Comment: Yes, I should of specified this is for V1 Aurora

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a security group issue. You need to add the security group that your next app is on to the RDS inbound security group.

Comment: The OP is using the data API. It doesn't require network connectivity in the same way as would a connection to a traditional DB.